# 'printf' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, printf, unsigned

I am really new C and I am trying to run the following piece of code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  unsigned long i = 1UL << 2;
  int j = (i==4);
  printf('%d', j);
  return 0;
}
```

But it's giving the error:

```
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:6:10: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   printf('%d', j);
          ^
prog.c:6:10: warning: passing argument 1 of 'printf' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
In file included from prog.c:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:362:12: note: expected 'const char * restrict' but argument is of type 'int'
 extern int printf (const char *__restrict __format, ...);
```

I am not sure what's wrong here. Any help?

Comment: Single quotes. Use Double quotes for a string "%d".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use single quotes for a printf statement. Try this:

```
printf("%d", j);
```

Answer (score 3):

`'%d'` is a multi-character literal, as you've enclosed more than one character in single quotation characters. Its value is implementation defined, but the C standard insists on it being an `int` type. (Hence the compiler diagnostic "pointer from an integer").

You want `"%d"` instead, that is use double quotation characters.

`printf` takes a `const char*` pointer as the first argument. Formally `"%d"` is a `const char[3]` type, but via a mechanism called *pointer decay* it becomes a suitable value for that first argument.